# How do I select a workbook with a dynamic name?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

This is my current VBA code. I would like to make the week number to increase by 1 every week. (so UAE_WK_2)

```
    Sub HelloALL3()
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Hello12"
    Windows("UAE_WK_1.xlsm").Activate
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Hello13"
    Windows("UAE_WK_1.xlsm").Activate
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Hello14"
    Windows("UAE_WK_1.xlsm").Activate
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Hello15"
    Windows("UAE_WK_1.xlsm").Activate
    Application. Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Hello16"

   
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple loop for week number

```
Sub test()
  Dim weekNum As Integer
  
  For weekNum = 1 To 4
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Hello12"
    Windows("UAE_WK_" & weekNum & ".xlsm").Activate
  Next weekNum
  
End Sub
```

Comment: If the number of weeks is incremental, so if I'm at week 40 and I keep increasing the number every week, what changes can I make? I'm new to VBA and I'm lost a bit

Comment: If I understand you can just change this row: For weekNum = 1 To 40